# Prove that a pair of irrational numbers is the solution to a quadratic polynomial.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose a, b are two irrational numbers such that ab is rational and a+b is rational. Then a, b are the solution to a quadratic polynomial with integer coeffecients.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are roots of a quadratic, can you write down that quadratic?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, as seen in Berci's answer right?

Comment: Berci's answer gives you one quadratic which has those two roots. Now, can you find *all* the quadratics that have those two roots? Hint; not every quadratic has a coefficient of $1$ for the $x^2$ term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a$, $b$ are two irrational numbers such that $ab$ is rational and $a+b$ is rational. Then $a$, $b$ are the solution to a quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients.

**Proof:**

Because $a+b$ and $ab$ are rational,  from the definition
of a rational number we can write
$$a+b = \frac{m}{n}, \quad\mbox{and}\quad ab = \frac{p}{q},$$
where $m$, $n$, $p$ and $q$ are integers.  Now we can
write
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x-a)(x-b) &=& x^2 -(a+b)x + ab\\
&=& x^2 - \frac{m}{n} x + \frac{p}{q} \\
&=& \frac{1}{nq}\left(nq\, x^2 - mq\, x + np\right).  
\end{eqnarray*}
So we have  a quadratic 
polynomial with integer
coefficients ($nq$, $mq$ and $np$), and obviously 
the roots of this polynomial
are $a$ and $b$. Therefore 
we have the proof.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$(x-a)(x-b)=x^2-(a+b)x+ab\,.$$

Comment: So I'm supposed to show that u,v are the solutions?

Comment: What are $u$, $v$? I don't see them in the question, nor in Berci's answer.

Comment: First I wrote $u,v$ in place of $a,b$ in my answer, then I realized that these are just the $a,b$ in the question.

Comment: @grayQuant: The exercise: conditions: $a+b,\ ab\in\Bbb Q$. Claim: show that $a,b$ are the roots for a polynomial $\in\Bbb Z[x]$. In my hint, every number on the right hand side is rational (=fraction). Multiply by a common multiplier of the two denominators and you're there.

Comment: What are the common denominators?

Comment: A rational number is a fraction: numerator/denominator. Now you are given two rationals ($a+b$ and $ab$).

Comment: Just do an example, grayQuant. Take $a=2/3$, $b=4/5$, and see what happens.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh that works, understood.